# Lotus Notes defaulting to user's name rather than the display name on the email?

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

We have a process which sends out emails over smtp and while it uses the same underlying email address for each email it uses a different display name:

eg.

> Email 1 - Email Address: test@test.com - Display Name: "Hello World"
>   Email 2 - Email Address: test@test.com - Display Name: "Goodbye World"

In Exchange and Outlook this works correctly.

In Domino and Lotus Notes this doesn't work if the underlying email address matches a local email address. In that case Notes displays the configured name of the user ignoring the per email display name.

The problem I'm faced with is that of an inbound email which has a fake display name being "corrected" by Lotus Notes because it matches a local user's email address.

Is there a way to have Lotus Notes show the display name in preference to the user's true name?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `RouterTranslateSpecial=0` to the NOTES.INI? It will tell the server to not check against your directory.

Note: That means that your users can change their internet address by going to their local names.nsf, and changing it there.

You need to restart the router task after the change.

```
tell router quit
load router
```

Reference: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/routertranslatespecial

Comment: Doesn't this only affect outbound emails? The problem I'm faced with is that of an inbound email which has a fake display name being "corrected" by Lotus Notes because it matches a local user's email address.

Comment: Yes. Only outgoing. I thought you had an agent running pointing to your Lotus Domino to send an internal email via SMTP. Then, Lotus checks the directory to match the destination, and deliver to the correct mailbox.